# how to get name based on id from DB table in yii framework

Tags: yii

i am developing web application by using yii framework, i have one table called "userprofile" in my database. i have tried to export userprofile data to excel file, everything is working fine this is my userprofile table fields
user profile table

```
 id  username   password   studentname   classid   parentname      email
 1.   xxxxx      asdf        yyyyy          2         pqrs        xy@gmail.com
```

classname table

```
  classid  classname
    1.       xxxxx
    2.       yyyyy
    3.       zzzzz
```

In my controller i have one function called actionExcelexport() and it has

```
$content = $this->renderPartial("excel",array("model"=>Puserprofile::model()->findAll()),true);
```

In above line i am calling one excel file called excel and this is my excel.php

```
<table>

    <tr>

          <td style="background-color: #555;color:#fff">User Name</td>
          <td style="background-color: #555;color:#fff">Student Name</td>
          <td style="background-color: #555;color:#fff">ClassID</td>
          <td style="background-color: #555;color:#fff">Parent Name</td>
          <td style="background-color: #555;color:#fff">Email</td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($model as $data):?>
    <tr>

           <td> <?php echo $data->username ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $data->studentname ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $data->classid   ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $data->parentname ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $data->email ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>


</table>
```

my reqirement:-
In my excel file i want to get classname instead of classid for example if my classs id is '2', classname 'yyyy' should get in excel file how to retrive classname based on classid could you please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got solution for my problem 
In my excel.php, instead of this line
   classid   ?>

i changed 
  class->classname?>

class->classname = my userprofile model has relation function and it has some relation because i am using foreign key for my table so i am taking this 'class' from my model and this is ('classname') my database field name